# How to add a custom text to a field (translatable) label

Tags: extjs, pimcore

I have an object with a localizedfields data:

[image]

I want to customize the Backend UI for my DataObject, because it's not possible, that field(-s) is required only for one language.

I know, how can I check the mandatories in PHP Event Listener, but I can not find any info, how can I add an asterisk to a field label only for German language.

[image]

Here is my JS:

```js
pimcore.registerNS('pimcore.test.plugin');

pimcore.test.plugin = Class.create(pimcore.plugin.admin, {
    getClassName: function () {
        return 'pimcore.test.plugin';
    },

    pimcoreReady: function (params,broker) {
    },

    initialize: function () {
        pimcore.plugin.broker.registerPlugin(this);
    },

    postOpenObject: function (object, type) {
        if (object.data.general.o_className === 'Product') {
            // add an asterisk to field label
        }
    },
});

let PimcoreTestPlugin = new pimcore.test.plugin();
```

Update 1: I have found in Pimcore Sources the part, that adds an asterisk to any field, if field is required, but how can I extend / override them?

```js
pimcore.registerNS("pimcore.object.helpers.edit");
pimcore.object.helpers.edit = {

    getRecursiveLayout: function (l, noteditable, context, skipLayoutChildren, onlyLayoutChildren, dataProvider, disableLazyRendering) {
        ...

        // add asterisk to mandatory field
        l.titleOriginal = l.title;
        if(l.mandatory) {
            l.title += ' <span style="color:red;">*</span>';
        }

        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it with PimCore, but the solution would be to use data-binding:

*In Modern*

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    bind: {required: '{isGerman}'}
}]
```

*In Classic*

```
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.form.field.Text', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    config: {
        allowBlank: true
    }
});

...
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    bind: {allowBlank: '{!isGerman}'}
}]
```

if allowBlank|required are will add the asterix.

- required will add the asterix if true. allow
- Blank will add the asterix if false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm not sure, that it helps me... I have found a part in Pimcore package, that adds an asterisk, but I don't know, how can I extend/override them...

Comment: That would be `l.mandatory && langsetting.de`

Comment: But how can extend this helper from pimcore?

Comment: Since you did not post how the language settings can be read, it is impossible to help any further. Could be that the context holds the current language, but I cannot tell, Without further information .

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom data type, where you specify the languages that are allowed to be edited / where it should be shown. In Pimcore this is done via CoreExtensions on the backend side and a custom data tag in JS.

https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Extending_Pimcore/Bundle_Developers_Guide/Adding_Object_Datatypes.html